Basic question about changing track at flight level
I'm a beginner private pilot flying VFR in Europe. I think I've heard that in the US it's not so common to fly at flight levels on small aircraft, but in Europe the transition altitude can be quite low enough for small planes, and there are definitely places you can fly VFR at FLs.
I want to go out and practice this sometimes (the rule is VFR flights fly at FL+500ft). But there is a basic question I haven't clearly discussed anywhere, which is if I change track such that I have to ascend or descend to a different FL according to the even/odd rule, what is the procedure? Change track first and then descend (for example)? Or descend first? Or do both more-or-less simultaneously?  Though at 500ft/m there will still be about 2 minutes of transition either way. How can this be ensured safely?

Airline pilot here who did all his training in the UK. I could be wrong, but there may be no need to fly at a FL even if above transition alt. The only time I flew flight levels during training was along airways under IFR. VFR would allow you to fly at any altitude want to -  unless you are under radar control, then the controller will instruct you to fly at a particular altitude/FL.

The ICAO rule for VFR cruising altitude is as follows:

Except where otherwise indicated in air traffic control
clearances or specified by the appropriate ATS authority, VFR
flights in level cruising flight when operated above 900 m
(3 000 ft) from the ground or water, or a higher datum as
specified by the appropriate ATS authority, shall be conducted
at a flight level appropriate to the track as specified in the
Tables of cruising levels in Appendix 3.

These cruising levels are altitudes below the transition altitude and flight levels above. There is no difference in the rules except what altimeter setting you should be using.
Unless preempted by local laws, there are no rules about how cruising level changes should be made. You should avoid flying in the wrong direction for the altitude you are flying for an extended period of time.
From a safety standpoint, the primary means of staying safe is "see and avoid." Radar services/ADS-B/TCAS and other technology can help enhance your safety.
